# How do I initialize an empty NSMutableAttributedString in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

With this code it tells me that `'String' is not convertible to 'NSMutableAttributedString'`

`var textViewString:NSMutableAttributedString = ""`

How do I properly initialize this string as empty? (It needs to be empty as I iterate through a loop appending items to the string.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an empty mutable attributed string simply with

```
var textViewString = NSMutableAttributedString()
```

Answer (score 13):

You can define it like this

```
var textViewString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
```

Comment: Although you don't need the explicit type since Swift can infer the type from the initializer. Martin's answer is the preferred syntax.